# If $A$ is a real unitary matrix then $A$ is similar to $A^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm trying to prove the following statement :

If $A$ is a real unitary matrix then $A$ is similar to $A^*$.

Here is what I have so far:

$A$ is unitary and therefore is unitary diagonalizable. Thus, there is unitary $P$ and diagonal $D$ such that : $P^{*}AP = D$.

In order to show that $A$ is similar to $A^*$ I should show that : $P^{*}A^*P = D$ (That is, both $A$ and $A^*$ have the same eigenvalues).

But all I know about $A^*$ is that $A^* \overbrace{=}^{A \ is \ unitary} A^{-1} \overbrace {=}^{A \ is \ real} A^t$.

Can you please give an hint how can I continue from here?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. You know that $A$ is a real unitary matrix but $P$ might be just unitary.

Comment: More generally: if two real matrices are similar over the complex numbers, does it follow that they are similar over the reals?

Comment: I think not. If $A$ and $B$ are similar such that $P^{-1}AP=B$ and $P$ is non real matrix then the matrices are similar over the complex numbers but aren't similar over the reals. Edit : On second though, if $P$ is non real matrix then it can't be that $A$ and $B$ are both real. It seems like the answer is correct.

Comment: If $P^{-1}AP=B$ with complex $P$, find real $P_1$ with $P_1^{-1}AP_1=B$ ...

Comment: @GEdgar I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: "All complex matrices are similar to their transposes" is maybe what you want to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all not all real unitary matrices can be diagonalized over the reals, for example a 45 degree rotational operator in $\mathbb{R}^2$--it has no real eigenvalue. They are always unitarily diagonalized over the complex field though.

Now if you assume $A$ has only real eigenvalues, $P^*AP=D$, then clearly $(P^*AP)^* =P^*A^*P = D^*=D$

If however $D$ is not real, you don't have $D^*=D$ in general. But since the eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, they come in conjugate pairs. This means that $D$ and $D^*$ have the same spectrum, hence is similar by a permutation matrix.

Comment: I don't assume that $A$ has only real eigenvalues of course. Although, I appreciate you did point it out. The thing I don't understand is why, in case $D$ is not real, $D$ and  $D^*$ have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $D$, then it is a root of the characteristic polynomial $P(D)$, so $\bar{\lambda}$ is a root of $P(D)$, hence also an eigenvalue. But here we assume $P(A)$ is real.

Comment: Oh! You mean that $\bar{\lambda}$ must be an eigenvalue of $D$ (or root of $P(D)$) because otherwise $P(D)\notin R[X]$ ? And also why do you assume that $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $D^*$?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB Yes.$\mathbb{R}[x]$

Comment: Can you please comment on my last edit? I've added one more question.

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB Because since $D$ is diagonal $D^* = \bar{D^T}=\bar{D}$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)